# Any way to reboot a iDevice that is connected to a USB port via terminal (Mac terminal)?

Tags: macos, iphone, terminal, command-line

So, I am making a program to reboot iDevices (if there power buttons are broken), is there any way to induce the iDevice to reboot via the Mac shell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`idevicediagnostics` is a Linux tool which can help here. It is also available for macOS according to [these instructions](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/use-libimobiledevice-to-view-ios-logs/).

Once installed you can use

```
idevicediagnostics restart
```

to restart your device.

To restart a specific device connected to a macbook that has more than one device connected to, use:

```
idevicediagnostics -u udidnumber restart
```

Comment: Why does this have 2 upvotes and the other one about the SAME command 2 downvotes?!

Comment: Probably because the other answer doesn't indicate how to get the tool mentioned also on macOS.

Comment: This oddly shut my iPhone 5 on iOS 10.1 down and I had to manually turn it back on

Answer (score 7):

To install [this third-party program](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice), on the Terminal:

```
brew install libimobiledevice
```

Use:

```
idevicediagnostics restart
```

Comment: Thank you. This allowed me force a restart on an iOS 16 iPhone that was completely unresponsive and would not respond to any hardware button presses. Never seen this issue before but the OS was completely locked up on the Lock Screen, despite time and some minor animations still rendering. Forcing a restart with idevicediagnostics resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

idevicediagnostics restart

you can substitute shutdown for restart.

on
Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This site is about Apple hardware -- the OP is asking how you can do this from the command line of an OS X-equipped machine, not an machine running Ubuntu.